# ¿Como puedo crear una pila auxiliar o como puedo invertir una pila en c++?

Tags: c++

aquí vengo con una duda que es la siguiente, me encuentro practicando para un examen que tendré mañana sobre pilas y colas, y haciendo unos ejercicios para practicar, me tope con este que me pide invertir una pila, usando otra pila (o hasta la misma pila creo), el punto es que no sé como hacerlo, he intentado varias formas y a la final no me da ninguna, aquí el código que llevo hasta ahora (puede que lo siga modificando en el transcurso de lo que queda del día).

```
//Ejemplo 3: Análogo al ejemplo anterior, pero usando dos pilas en vez de una cola.

#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"pilas.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Pila *pila = NULL, p, p2;
    int dato;
    char opc;
    
    do{
        cout<<"Digite el numero: "; cin>>dato;
        
        p.agregarPila(pila,dato);
        
        cout<<"Desea agregar otro elemento(s/n): "; cin>>opc;
    }while((opc == 's') || (opc == 'S'));
    
    cout<<"Pila sin invertir"<<endl;
    while(pila != NULL){
        p.sacarPila(pila,dato);
        
        if(pila != NULL){
            cout<<dato<<" , ";
        }else{
            cout<<dato<<".";
        }
        
        p2.agregarPila(pila,dato);
    }
    
    while(pila != NULL){
        p2.sacarPila(pila,dato);
        
        if(pila != NULL){
            cout<<dato<<" , ";
        }else{
            cout<<dato<<".";
        }
    }
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Aqui el codigo de la libreria "pilas.h"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Pila{
private:
    int dato;
    Pila *siguiente;
public:
    void agregarPila(Pila *&,int); //Prototipo
    void sacarPila(Pila *&,int &);
    bool pila_vacia(Pila *);
};

//Función para agregar elementos a la pila
void Pila::agregarPila(Pila *&pila,int n){
    Pila *nuevo_nodo = new Pila();
    nuevo_nodo->dato = n;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = pila;
    pila = nuevo_nodo;

    // cout<<"\nElemento "<<n<<" agregado a PILA correctamente"<<endl;
}

//Funcion para quitar elementos de la pila
void Pila::sacarPila(Pila *&pila,int &n){
    Pila *aux = NULL;
    n = aux->dato;
    pila = aux->siguiente;
    delete aux;
}
```

Comment: Veo que `Pila` es `NULL` y entonces llamas a sus métodos, creo que deberías inicializarla con una instancia. Además sería bueno que nos muestres la implementación de `Pila` en sí misma, para ello puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/585836/edit) tu pregunta y agregar dicho código.

Comment: @HéctorM. como asi que la implementación de la pila? no comprendo, te refieres a los resultados que arroja?

Comment: Esta línea `Pila *pila = NULL` indica que estás declarando una variable llamada `pila` con un tipo de dato llamado `Pila` donde entiendo que `Pila` es una `class` (o `struct`) declarada por vos. El código fuente de esa `class` (o `struct`) es a lo que me refiero.

Comment: ah ya comprendo, pues sí, es una clase, ya editare la pregunta para que sea mas facil de comprender

Answer (score 2):

El problema está con el manejo de la memoria.

Además, la clase `Pila` en realidad representa a un nodo con responsabilidades de pila y tampoco es ***autocontenida*** en el sentido de que dependes de una variable externa (`pila`).

Si arreglas eso, el código podría verse así:

```
class Nodo {
    Nodo* siguiente;

public:
    Nodo(int dato){
        this->dato = dato;
        siguiente = nullptr;    
    }

    int dato;
    friend class Pila;
};

class Pila {
    Nodo* ultimo;

public:
    Pila(){
        ultimo = nullptr;
    }

    void agregar(Nodo* nodo){
        nodo->siguiente = ultimo;
        ultimo = nodo;
    }

    Nodo* sacar(){
        Nodo* aux = ultimo;
        ultimo = ultimo->siguiente;
        return aux;
    }

    void imprimir(){
        Nodo* aux = ultimo;
        while (aux){
            cout << aux->dato << ", ";
            aux = aux->siguiente;
        }
    }

    bool tieneElementos() {
        return ultimo;
    }
};
```

De esta forma necesitas liberar la memoria por tu cuenta. La ventaja es que las funciones son más pequeñas y te da la oportunidad de reutilizar nodos. Reservar memoria es una operación costosa así que es bueno poder hacerlo.

Como buena práctica, es más natural que si existen salidas sean mediante `return` y no mediante los parámetros de la función. Quiero decir, no modificar una referencia pasada como parámetro, a diferencia del código que escribiste.

De hecho, si una función no va a modificar el contenido de una referencia, deberías hacerla constante.

También es buena idea limitar el acceso a la variable `siguiente` y que la clase `Pila` sí pueda modificarla.

Por eso `siguiente` es privada y es necesario usar [`friend`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) para que las variables y funciones privadas se vuelvan visibles a la clase `Pila`.

---

La función `main` quedaría así:

```
int main(){
    Pila pila, pilaInvertida;
    int dato;
    char opc;

    do{
        cout << "Digite el numero: "; cin >> dato;
        
        pila.agregar(new Nodo(dato));

        cout << "Desea agregar otro elemento(s/n): "; cin >> opc;
    } while((opc == 's') || (opc == 'S'));
    
    cout << "\nPila sin invertir\n";
    pila.imprimir();
    while (pila.tieneElementos()){
        auto nodo = pila.sacar();
        pilaInvertida.agregar(nodo);
    }
    cout << "\nPila invertida\n";
    pilaInvertida.imprimir();

    // Idealmente, liberas la memoria cuando no la necesitas más.
    // Estas 2 líneas podrían moverse a una función miembro, incluso el destructor.
    while (pilaInvertida.tieneElementos())
        delete pilaInvertida.sacar();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Podes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##jVRNb9swDL3rVxDZIc7QdB@91YlP22GXYkCvvaiy5hCQJUOS2w1tfntGSf6Qk2CYgDgW@UQ@kk8WXbdthDidPqAWqq8l7NA4byVvKzbbWtka@ye3OF8rfL49VIz1DnUDmrfSdVxIIFfJmFDcOXgwtYE3BrTC60dw2PQotZcE6fpnheJ@8haoPdTcm006EZY/oNtWwQj76Csn1xSKPLpXqvO2DPYIOLL4N0ZMp35ZwteQqP1ExUt2nKiG/YJqrzy25oxnQBUZvwTKGOTZXwzWwBsrG26LFFTTMzsettsqr2TMepmAoIvoQ0O5oOBZyGTm/e9/BUsvWeYZY6XvrQ4BLmvBtrPY4n/nez2gklCQMzsQljC9h90uHBumS5vVDazKBSxFjaArTI85v2djFHhCyO9KtgQ0rtjA23lZOcNjnD4LGmk56rGoKISOHjfx@UO/SOux5uUVRYkDt2A6USYStZkTjiWuvmGDNFqpSCOttOaeqgSBGqrqTNHTS8h7OwpHy9d0PeLV2Ayplimkk3xUGhhvDaVLXSjcJ73JU0a2sfw0nqIgC@z3sHbrDby/w7R/XIdsE7Ep25OOLaJrT92IzbFPephcZD7LJBkHGUTf@YgyYfCedBBkTjOP2EHb5aIv0zzmBoU7NY70GlMcjyxozoFyvueEZ9QF84lWTc2mCS/hC/Isk@Bn@uqcTl/YI/tKvzv28Bc).